# azure api management retrieving password from shell script ,saving it and deploying it

Tags: azure, jenkins-pipeline, azure-api-management, azure-cli

I had seen multiple examples how to use Azure API manager using powershell to retreive password for SCM but unable to find any example using it without powershell i.e. something execution in shell command line. i am also looking for example for saving and deploying  my api

Answer (score 0):

You can always inspect any Azure service API in action by doing what you need in Azure portal and seeing what requests get sent. Correlating them with documentation helps. So to get access token for SCM endpoint in APIM you need:

1. With any Azure credentials make a GET call to https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/.../resourceGroups/.../providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/.../tenant/access/git?api-version=2018-01-01

in response you will get a payload similar to:

```
{
    "id": "XXX",
    ...
}
```

2. Take "id" from that payload and make a POST call to https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/.../resourceGroups/.../providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/.../users/XXX/token?api-version=2018-01-01

you will get your token:

```
{
    "value":"..."
}
```